# PDOStatement: Getting different results between `fetchAll($mode);` and `setFetchMode($mode); fetchAll();`

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, fetch

I have a question regarding PDO.

Is there a difference between

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages";
$pdo = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages";
$pdo = $this->db->query($sql);
$pdo->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $pdo->fetchAll();
```

?

I get a different `$result` for each of them.

The documentation from PHP about these fetch modes is not very clear to me.

I have a table with different pages, and I want to fetch all the pages indexed by their ID.

The first method returns this:

```
[
   [id of page 1] => [
      [0] => [ page 1 ],
   ],
   [id of page 2] => [
      [0] => [ page 2 ],
   ],
   ...
]
```

When I do the second method, I only get:

```
[
   [0] => [ page 1 ],
   [1] => [ page 2 ],
   [3] => [ page 3 ],
   ...
]
```

I want it like this:

```
[
   [id of page 1] => [ page 1 ],
   [id of page 2] => [ page 2 ],
   [id of page 3] => [ page 3 ],
   ...
]
```

The first one is good enough for me because I can easily tweak it with the array map function:

```
array_map('reset', $result);
```

Comment: Oh, well i didn't think it was relevant because I was just asking if there is a difference between the two, and if so, what... But maybe it's better if I add it

Comment: there should be any difference

Comment: SO i added an example of what it returns, what is the difference, because to me it seems the code should return the same...

Answer (score 5):

The explanation seems to be that `fetchAll()` and `setFetchMode()` support  different sets of `PDO::FETCH__` constants.

I think `setFetchMode()` ignores `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`, but not `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

I confirmed this from the PHP source code, see the [`setFetchMode()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/93f9ee7217c55c23b10a5ae01df677502ac51773/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L1826) implementation. The list of constants supported by `setFetchMode` does not include `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`.

---

### Why the results of `setFetchMode()` and `fetchAll()` are different

#### The code:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root');

// print the default output, no constants
$sql = "SELECT * FROM service_table";
$q = $db->query($sql);
$result = $q->fetchAll();
echo 'Result 0' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($result);

// use fetchAll() with constants
$sql = "SELECT * FROM service_table";
$q = $db->query($sql);
$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo 'Result 1' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($result);

// use setFetchMode with constants
$sql = "SELECT * FROM service_table";
$q = $db->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $q->fetchAll();
echo 'Result 2' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($result);
```

#### Test data

```
mysql> select * from test.service_table;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | one  |
|  2 | two  |
+----+------+
```

#### Result 0

This is the default, results are not grouped and there are both name-based and index-based fields:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    'id' => string(1) "1"
    [0] => string(1) "1"
    'name' => string(3) "one"
    [1] => string(3) "one"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(4) {
    'id' => string(1) "2"
    [0] => string(1) "2"
    'name' => string(3) "two"
    [1] => string(3) "two"
  }
}
```

#### Result 1

This is the result of `$q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. We have the effects of both `FETCH_GROUP` and `FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
array(2) {
  [1] => array(1) {
    [0] => array(1) {
      'name' => string(3) "one"
    }
  }
  [2] => array(1) {
    [0] => array(1) {
      'name' => string(3) "two"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Result 2

This is the result of `$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, we have only the effect of `FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    'id' => string(1) "1"
    'name' => string(3) "one"
  }
  [1] => array(2) {
    'id' => string(1) "2"
    'name' => string(3) "two"
  }
}
```

This way, `FETCH_GROUP` works for `fetchAll()`, but doesn't work for `setFetchMode()`. `FETCH_ASSOC` works in both cases.

#### PHP Documentation

Now, an indirect confirmation from docs:

Here is the list of all [PDO constants](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php). The description for `PDO::FETCH_FUNC` says:

> Allows completely customize the way data is treated on the fly (only valid inside `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`).

So we know that at least this constant only works for `fetchAll()`, and can assume that other constants may work not everywhere.

Also if we look at the docs for [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), we see a limited list of constants there.

For example `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` and `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` are present in the [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) description, but are not present in the `fetch()` description.

So I think constants related to multi-row operations, such as `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`, are only used for `fetchAll()` and ignored by `fetch()` and `setFetchMode()`.

---

### How to fetch an array indexed by ID

I tried few combinations and it looks like `FETCH_GROUP` + `FETCH_UNIQUE` does it.

#### Code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM service_table";
$q = $db->query($sql);
$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

#### Result

```
array(2) {
  [1] => array(1) {
    'name' => string(3) "one"
  }
  [2] => array(1) {
    'name' => string(3) "two"
  }
}
```

Another option can be to use `FETCH_FUNC` with custom function to format data, see the [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) docs.

Comment: I think you can better remove your examples here, We already have an example in the question, so better to only explain the reason, not a new example.

Comment: @TaReQMahMooD The question only touches the difference between fetchall and setFetchMode. My explanation is based on comparing them with the default behaviour (not flags) which is not present in the question. I am afraid it will be complex to follow the logic if I remove examples.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great explanation and the example only bolsters it, enjoy the the bounty :)

Comment: @Arth thanks, and I was also able to confirm my assumptions from the php sources, FETCH_GROUP is just ignored by setFetchMode. I updated the answer.